# How do I implement heartbeat in a plain Spring websocket library ( not stomp)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Since my client does not support stomp library I need to implement using plain spring `websocket` library. Is there any default heartbeat mechanism or a property to setup the heartbeat? thanks

Currently if the client detects connection break, it tries to re-establish the connection. Is there any downside on not implementing websocket heartbeat?